# Is there a Google Cloud Run node.js package / samples / docs?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-run

I've been searching the web, npm, SO, the google cloud docs site, and anywhere else I can think of for a node.js package for Google Cloud Run, so that I can deploy a GCR container programmatically, to no avail.  Is there one I'm missing?

It appears the only way to invoke Google Cloud Run API's is via the REST API [1].  There does not appear to be a guide on how to call these API's.

I can more or less deduce how to do this by logging the http calls from the gcloud SDK command [2], but surely there is a better way?

[1] https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest

[2] `gcloud run deploy <service-name> --platform managed --image gcr.io/<project>/<service-name> --log-http`

Comment: Going through the HTTP logs generated by the "gcloud run deploy" command, it's relatively straightforward (albeit cumbersome) to create an HTTP PUT request to the ```https://us-central1-run.googleapis.com/apis/serving.knative.dev/v1/namespaces/{project}/services/{service}?alt=json``` endpoint.  The gcloud SDK will then poll the same endpoint using GET calls until the new revision is serving 100% of traffic.  Overall, doable but painful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: Does not exist yet.

Since Cloud Run is relatively new, and is GA since [last November](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/release-notes#November_14_2019), it seems that package you are looking does not exists yet.

From here what I can tell you is that you can:

1. File a Feature Request in the [Cloud Run Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=608076&template=0), so the team developing the product will be aware that there are people asking for this.
2. Build your own basic client library. Here you have a [Google tutorial for creating a simple library using a Google API](https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/building-a-client-library). I'm afraid this one would be time consuming, but faster than waiting for the Feature Request that I mentioned in 1

**UPDATE**

Google support has replied [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/152337208).

> I think [this](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/latest/run/classes/Run.html) may be the API you are looking for. Please say if otherwise.

Notice this seems to be a generic code-generated Nodejs client library, and documentation is pretty lacking. No examples either.

Answer (score 0):

When you are stuck with Client library, because the library doesn't exists or it's not up-to-date, you can use the discovery API

On [Cloud Run documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest) you have the reference of the endpoint: https://run.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1

For using it in NodeJS, you can use the [googleapis library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client)